# Getting multiple variables to show up in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two queries:

```
Select count(*) as countOne where field = '1'
Select count(*) as countTwo where field = '2'
```

What I want to see after executing these queries in my results viewer:

```
countOne | countTwo
      23 |      123
```

How can I get the results from both queries by only running one query?

Comment: Are these both selects against the same table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN field = '1' THEN 1 END) AS countOne,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN field = '2' THEN 1 END) AS countTwo
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  field IN ( '1', '2' )
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to run each as a subselect eg.

```
SELECT 
(
Select count(*) where field = '1' as countOne,
Select count(*) where field = '2' as countTwo
)
```

BUt this is not necesarily the best way

Another wayto do it would be to Group by field and then do PIVOT to select out each group as a separate column.

Comment: This is called sub-querying? is it just very inefficient? if so, what is a better way?

Comment: It will be as data intensive as the two individual selects. I've specified an alternative, PIVOT, in the answer, but will have to lookup the syntax (I don't do it very often)